# How can I 'get' all instances of a dom element that matches 2 attribute property/value pairs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JQuery, I know  I have the ability to get all elements that match the attribute name/value pair that is passed into it's `$()` selector:

```
$("[attribute_name='attribute_value']")
```

I have done so in my application where I do the following

```
 $("[gridster-item='tile']")

<tile class="ng-scope gridster-item" tilevalue="1" gridster-item="tile" row="0" col = "0" ng-repeat="tile in selectedTiles"> </tile>
```

**The Problem:**
Using the same idea, how can I grab all instances of an element that match not one but **two** attribute `name/value` pairs? Say I wanted to grab all elements that have `row=0` and `col=0`?

Comment: `$('[row="0"],[col="0"]')` for `OR` and `$('[row="0"][col="0"]')` for `AND`

Comment: See this link https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Comment: thanks that really helps. is it possible to replace the interger values with a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this...

```
$( '[row="0"][col="0"]' )
```

Or with vars

```
var row = 0, col = 0
$( '[row="' + row + '"][col="' + col + '"]' )
```

You can also filter the elements after querying them...

```
$( '[row="0"]' ).filter( '[col="0"]' )
```

This is specially useful if you have the query cached as in...

```
var els = $( '[row="0"]' )
var elsC0 = els.filter( '[col="0"]' )
```

Again with vars

```
var row = 0, col = 0
$( '[row="' + row + '"]' ).filter( '[col="' + col + '"]' )
```

This will get all elements with attribute row set to 0 then will shortlist (filter) the elements with attribute col="0".

Lemme know how it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('[row=0][col=0]').css('background-color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span row="0" col = "0">da</span>
<span row="01" col = "10">da</span>
<span row="02" col = "03">da</span>
<span row="04" col = "50">da</span>
<span row="a0" col = "0d">da</span>
<span row="0" col = "0">da</span>
<span row="0" col = "0">da</span>
```

Use `$('[row=0][col=0]')` selector

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to follow this syntax but replace the integers with variables? (ex: rowVar = 0 ; colVar = 0)